# How to process read receipt vs delivery receipt vs bounceback (JavaMail)

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail

We have a requirement coming in to try to, as best we can, determine the progress an email made to the user. We know it's not 100%, and the solution I'm advising is to use an image/watermark in the email that is loaded from a URL that would record that the image was read...BUT there's a fair chance that they're going to rely on read/delivery receipts and bouncebacks.  So I wanted to learn more about it, both to be ready and so I can argue against it in the meeting.

If we were to set up an email mailbox to receive bouncebacks, read receipts, and delivery receipts and then write a java program to poll said mailbox, get the messages and inspect them.  How could I tell the bounces from the read receipts from the delivery receipts from the spam?  I know that the read and delivery receipt REQUESTS are SMTP headers.  Do the returning messages have a header that tells which they are?  And do the bouncebacks?  And if so, what are they?  If not, am I parsing the message body?  Does that differ from server to server?  Is there any standard (or close to standard) thing in it?  Like the word 'undeliverable' is always there?

I tried to google, but all the hits I could get were about REQUESTING the receipts.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I tell the bounces from the read receipts from the delivery receipts from the spam?

Jakarta Mail and JavaMail have [com.sun.mail:dsn](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/) artifact that have support for parsing and [creating messages containing Delivery Status Notifications](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/1.6/apidocs/).
Those classes have constructors that can parse the delivery notifications but it may not be able to parse any read receipt.